# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am getting error
src/sr_main.c: In function ‘main’:
src/sr_main.c:72: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before numeric constant
src/sr_main.c:72: warning: statement with no effect
src/sr_main.c:81: error: ‘natEnabled’ undeclared (first use in this function

I am not getting clue why this error is coming. Everything seems to be correct syntactically.

```
59 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 60 {
 61   int c;
 62   char *host   = DEFAULT_HOST;
 63   char *user = 0;
 64   char *server = DEFAULT_SERVER;
 65   char *rtable = DEFAULT_RTABLE;
 66   char *filter = DEFAULT_FILTER;
 67   char *template = NULL;
 68   unsigned int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
 69   unsigned int topo = DEFAULT_TOPO;
 70   char *logfile = 0;
 71   struct sr_instance sr;
 72   int natEnabled 0;
 73 
 74   printf("Using %s\n", VERSION_INFO);
 75 
 76   while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hs:n:v:p:u:t:r:l:T:")) != EOF)
 77   {
 78     switch (c)
 79     {
 80     case 'n':
 81       natEnabled =1;
 82       break;
 83     case 'h':
 84       usage(argv[0]);
 85       exit(0);
 86       break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, listen to the compiler, you need `int natEnabled=0;`

Answer (score 2):

```
72   int natEnabled 0;
```

That is probably supposed to read `int natEnabled = 0;`

Comment: @JimBuck at one point in the past (back in research unix v6) you didn't need the '=' sign.

Comment: Yes, but this post was created in 2011, not 1975, and the line number of the error points exactly to this line. ;)

Comment: @Wyatt8740 is there any way to make gcc accept these old declarations? Would be convenient when compiling historical source code…

Comment: @lucas.werkmeister not that I could find. GCC has a bazillion options though, so I could have missed something. I think you'd probably have to patch the source of either GCC or unix v6.

Answer (score 1):

Line 72, you forgot the equals sign.

Should be `int natEnabled = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look, you incorrectly declared `natEnabled` on line 72. You are missing the `=` sign when you declare the variable.